# JOIN, UNION, MERGE?

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating an inventory system for Magic the Gathering Cards and need to update the prices with the main card info.

I have two tables, Cards and Prices

Cards has the following columns: 
ID, Name, Ed, Price

Prices has the following columns: 
Name, Ed, Price

I need Cards.Price to be replaced with the value in Prices.Price.

Below is the code for two different attempts to make this work (I know I am probably making this a lot harder than it needs to be....)

Attempt #1

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Cards";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $name=$row['Name'];
    $ed=$row['Ed'];

    $queryb = "SELECT Price FROM Prices WHERE Name='".$name."' AND Ed='".$ed."'";
    $resultb = mysql_query($queryb) or die(mysql_error());
    $rowb = mysql_fetch_array($resultb) or die(mysql_error());
    $newPrice = $rowb['Price'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE Cards SET Price='".$newPrice."'");
    }
```

Attempt #2

```
    $queryCards = "SELECT * FROM Cards";
    $queryPrices = "SELECT * FROM Prices";
    $dblink = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    mysql_select_db($dbname, $dblink);


    $resultCards = mysql_query($queryCards) or die(mysql_error());
    $resultPrices = mysql_query($queryPrices) or die(mysql_error());
    $rowCards = mysql_fetch_array($resultCards) or die(mysql_error());
    $rowPrices = mysql_fetch_array($resultPrices) or die(mysql_error());



    if ($rowCards['Name']==$rowPrices['Name'] && $rowCards['Ed']==$rowPrices['Ed'])
    {
    $newPrice = $rowPrices['Price'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE Cards SET Price='".$newPrice."' WHERE
    Name='".$rowCards['Name']."' AND Ed='".$rowCards['Ed']."'"); 
    }
    while($rowPrices = mysql_fetch_array($resultPrices))
       {
       if ($rowCards['Name']==$rowPrices['Name'] && 
                    $rowCards['Ed']==$rowPrices['Ed'])
          {
          $newPrice = $rowPrices['Price'];
          mysql_query("UPDATE Cards SET Price='".$newPrice."' WHERE 
                       Name='".$rowCards['Name']."' AND Ed='".$rowCards['Ed']."'");
          }  
       }       

   $rowPrices = mysql_fetch_array($resultPrices) or die(mysql_error());

   while($rowCards = mysql_fetch_array($resultCards))
   {
   while($rowPrices = mysql_fetch_array($resultPrices))
       {
       if ($rowCards['Name']==$rowPrices['Name'] &&
                $rowCards['Ed']==$rowPrices['Ed'])
            {
            $newPrice = $rowPrices['Price'];
                mysql_query("UPDATE Cards SET Price='".$newPrice."' WHERE 
                     Name='".$rowCards['Name']."' AND Ed='".$rowCards['Ed']."'");
                }  
                }      
    }
```

Comment: Do you have control over the table structure?  You should really place a foreign key on the price table to the card table.  Then you can run the sql statement: "update cards join price on cards.id = price.card_id set cards.price = price.price".

Comment: Table structure is tough to keep consistent. Cards is from gatherer.wizards.com database. I was able to download the data with help from a third party program that got the ID from the database. The prices come from http://magic.tcgplayer.com/magic_price_guides.asp and no id is given. I hand copied the prices, would eventually need to automate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE Cards 
   JOIN Prices ON Cards.Name = Prices.Name AND Cards.Ed = Prices.Ed 
SET Cards.Price = Prices.Price
```

Comment: I tried this and it took a few seconds to process, but the Price is still blank in the Cards table. Forgot to mention and hopefully it does not matter that the Card.Price fields are all blank at the moment.

Comment: I had to reformat the text and it worked fine. Had a trash character at the beginning of the Price table fields. Thanks for your help.